# Hey. I have error in the Compiling can you someone help? Linux

Tags: c++, unix, ubuntu, operating-system

i try to compile code in c in the terminal the compiler throw me message i cant understand 
it..

the massege is :

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ gcc -o run execute.cpp
execute.cpp: In function ‘void KillCommand(char*)’:
execute.cpp:389:57: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘char’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
execute.cpp: In function ‘void GetCommand(char*, char**, char*, char*, char*)’:
execute.cpp:477:129: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
/tmp/ccg3lDy1.o:(.eh_frame+0x10b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: it's a linker error, probably you're missing some -L<library>. Try compiling with g++ (it defines a couple of C++ things)

Answer (score 4):

If you are compiling C++ code, use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

It sets some flags differently, and most importantly it links with the C++ runtime library automatically.